# Why are there empty lines in the output of my command?: find ~/x/y/ | shuf > ~/Desktop/z.txt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, find

As it turns out the reason for this problem was one filename with several newlines. (No idea how that happened.)

```
find ~/x/y/ | shuf > ~/Desktop/z.txt
```

This command works pretty much as expected except some empty lines appear in the "z.txt" file. This is inconvenient because the next step is to pick the uppermost file and open it, an empty line would obviously be useless. I'm curious why this happens and if there is some "standard" solution to the problem (some option?), or, alternatively, some robust and simple solution (an extra command to delete empty lines?).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuf` doesn't add empty lines, so they must come from the output of `find`. This indicates that there are files whose name contains two consecutive newlines somewhere in that directory. You can look see what they are with the command

```
find ~/x/y/ -name '*
*' -print -exec echo '========'
```

or

```
find ~/x/y/ -name '*
*' -exec ls -q
```

To cope with file names containing newlines with your `shuf` command, use a null byte as the separator.

```
find ~/x/y/ -print0 | shuf -z
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why blank lines are appearing in your output file, but you can try filtering out blank lines before writing to the file.

```
find ~/x/y/ | shuf | grep -v '^$' > ~/Desktop/z.txt
```

---

In order to track down the source of the blank lines, try running `find` by itself.

```
find ~/x/y/ > ~/Desktop/z.txt
```

Do blank lines appear in `z.txt`? If so, it is likely that they are being created by `find`.

---

You can use zero-terminated items instead of newline-terminated items. When you select the first item from the list, just use the text from the first character to the first null character.

```
find ~/x/y/ -print0 | shuf -z > ~/Desktop/z.txt
```

Comment: Ah, yes, for some reason a file name with lots of newlines has been accepted in my old osx files (I don't think it normally does that).

Comment: Ok. :) Thanks for giving so quick and thorough answers!

Comment: In case you are unable to rename the file, I have added a method for working with the file to my answer.